# Why python GIL is not kicking in for this multithreaded code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multithreading, python-3.8

I run the following piece of pure python code and in my understanding GIL should kick in and avoid simultaneous access to variable `x` and hence `x` should have sum for first 10 million numbers but it doesn't work and gives different result every-time which makes me believe that there in no mutex when both threads are accessing variable `x`.

```
from threading import Thread

x = 0


def task_1():
    global x
    for i in range(5000000):
        x += i


def task_2():
    global x
    for i in range(5000001, 10000000):
        x += i


t1 = Thread(target=task_1)
t2 = Thread(target=task_2)

t1.start()
t2.start()

t1.join()
t2.join()

print(f"X value is {x}")
```

Comment: GIL does not prevent thread switching, it only means that no more than one Python thread from the same process is executed at any moment in time, regardless of how many cores there are.

Comment: In addition `int` is a C implemented type. C code can release the GIL.

Comment: `x += 1` is not an atomic operation. Read the docs concerning *augmented assignment*: **Unlike normal assignments, augmented assignments evaluate the left-hand side before evaluating the right-hand side**. That implies it is a two-step operation and the thread can give up control to another thread between the two steps. You should read the manual first.

Comment: What you won't end up with is the C level implementation of `x` pointing to some invalid pointer (e.g. one that's already been freed) and that's what the GIL ensures

Comment: @bereal would you add your comment as answer and add some more info if you would like so I can close the question.

Comment: @GauriShankarBadola isn't sheldonzy's answer already good enough?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`x += y` is not an atomic operation.
You can read more under [What kinds of global value mutation are thread-safe?](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/library.html#what-kinds-of-global-value-mutation-are-thread-safe)

Also, remember that multithreads in Python are not for CPU bound programs (like yours). The GIL here only means that only one thread will run at the same time, regardless of how many cores there are.

And note that your code is trying to sum the first 10 million numbers minus 5,000,000 since you skipped it in `task_2`, and it is not included in `task_1`.